# How could someone change a root password without modifying `chage -l root` date?

Tags: passwords, password-policy, centos

How could someone change the root password without changing `chage -l root` `Last password change` date? I know it was changed because it does not match the value in Keepass. I noticed when I tried to use `su` from a non-root account. My private key still worked. I updated many packages too if that matters (I had to restart `sshd` because it was not letting me in). OS is CentOS 6.5, on AWS EC2.

Comment: I'm not sure about how this can be done but your machine might be compromised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your system is using regular simple unix authentication, there's at least one way of changing a password assuming you have root access.

You can do this by simply editing the /etc/shadow file and pasting in a new password hash in place of the old one. This does not influence "chage -l" output as the change is done outside tools, so no other data (modification date etc) is modified.